# array of string in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to solve this problem without using arraylist.
i want to add the contact to its specific index in the array of strings. And then display all the added contacts in string format seperated by commas. 
My code gives the result of only last added contract: 
Contact [first=Bob, last=Moore, number=555-9756]
where is the problem in my code?
Is there any idea how to solve???

This class consist of the main method:

This is the main class:

```
public class ExampleApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PhoneBook pb = new PhoneBook("Personal book");
        System.out.println( pb.getName() );

        pb.add("Alice", "Green", "555-1234");
        pb.add("Mary", "Smith", "555-6784");
        pb.add("Bob", "Moore", "555-9756");

        System.out.println( pb.toString() );// here i want to display all the contracts seperated by commas

        System.out.println( pb.first() );// first contract

        System.out.println( pb.get(2) );// second contract 

        String toBeFound = new String("Moore");
        System.out.println( pb.find(toBeFound) );// display the found contract 
    }
}
```

This is the phonebook class:

```
public class PhoneBook {
    public static final int MAX = 10;
    public String name;
    String[] contracts = new String[MAX]; // i created an array of strings 
    Contact c;

  /**
   * Create a new phonebook with given name
   */
  public PhoneBook(String name) {  
      this.name = name;
  }

  /**
   * Return the phonebook name
   */
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  /**
   * Insert a new contact at the end
   */  
  public void add(String first, String last, String number){
     c=new Contact(first,last,number);

    for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++){ // i added for each array index the contracts strings 

            contracts[i]= c.toString();
    }

  }

  /**
   * Return the first contact
   */  
  public String first() {
      return get(1);
  }

  /**
   * Return the i-th contact (supposing that first 
   * index is 1)
   */
  public String get(int i) {
      String s =contracts[i].toString();
      return s;
  }

  /**
   * Return a string containing the list of textual 
   * representation of all contacts, separated by  ", ".
   * List starts with "("and ends with ")" 
   */
  public String toString() {
      String s= " ";
      for(int i=1;i<MAX;i++){ // here i tried to display the string looping the array 
          s=contracts[i].toString(); 
      }
      return s;
  }

  /**
   * Return the textual representation of first
   * contact containing "needle"
   */
  public String find(String needle) {
      //TODO: to be implemented 
      return null;
  }

}
```

This is the contact class :

```
public class Contact {
public String first;
public String last;
public String number;
public String[] contacts;
public Contact(String first, String last, String number) {
    this.first=first;
    this.last = last;
    this.number=number;
}
public String getFirst() {
    return first;
}
public void setFirst(String first) {
    this.first = first;
}
public String getLast() {
    return last;
}
public void setLast(String last) {
    this.last = last;
}
public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}
public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Contact [first=" + first + ", last=" + last + ", number="
            + number + "]";
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ArrayList for it. It will help you really much and you should make your veriables private.

```
private String first;
private String last;
private String number;

private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String pointer : list){

}
```

or you can make contact saver ArrayList

```
   private ArrayList<Contact> list = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    public Contact(String first, String last, String number) {
    this.first=first;
    this.last = last;
    this.number=number;
}
 public void add(String first, String last, String number){
     c=new Contact(first,last,number);
     list.add(c);
}
```

and you can access all veriables like that `list.get(i).first`.
You can save your contact class and contracts array in arraylist and it will give you more power to access. If you want to display your ArrayList, which index is not important, you need only ++i for it.

I changed your class look this:

```
public class PhoneBook {
    public static final int MAX = 10;
    public String name;
    String[] contracts = new String[MAX]; // i created an array of strings
    Contact c;
    private int count = 0;// saved last index of array
    public PhoneBook(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void add(String first, String last, String number) {
        c = new Contact(first, last, number);

        contracts[count] = c.toString(); // save your String inside of last index++
        count++;

    }
    public String first() {
        return get(1);
    }

    public String get(int i) {
        String s = contracts[i].toString();
        return s;
    }

    public String toString() {

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        if (contracts[i] != null)
            System.out.println(contracts[i].toString()); 
    }
    return "";
}

    public String find(String needle) {

        return null;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Contact {
    public String first;
    public String last;
    public String number;

    public Contact(String first, String last, String number) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contact [first=" + first + ", last=" + last + ", number="
                + number + "]";
    }

}
```

---

```
//Personal book
//Contact [first=Alice, last=Green, number=555-1234] 
//Contact[first=Mary, last=Smith, number=555-6784]
//Contact [first=Bob, last=Moore, number=555-9756]
```

you always delete your last toString method. Your Add method is wrong. You always turn 0 and write again inside of array.

Comment: thanks for the answer but here i am trying to solve without using arraylist

Comment: for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++){contracts[i]= c.toString();} You cant make it because you always delete your old code

Comment: @Niranjan your add method and toString method is wrong

Comment: i changed your code your for method is delete your old saves. You always go back to 0 and write again you add "nira" then you add "nira2" but the second time you delete your nira and write nira2 nira2. I changed your code and sent it again. Look your for loop inside of the add method, it always go to index 0 and write on it

Comment: @Niranjan your toString method returns 1 string because of it your code never display all phonebook look my toString method you can use it like that or you can make void method for it

Comment: Personal book
Contact [first=Mary, last=Smith, number=555-6784]
Contact [first=Bob, last=Moore, number=555-9756]

Contact [first=Mary, last=Smith, number=555-6784]
Contact [first=Bob, last=Moore, number=555-9756]
null
i got the above result !still first contact alice is missing !!!!

Comment: thanks for the help! i solved the problem : ya your code works ! the problem was with looping in toString() method !

Answer (score 0):

You should keep track of the last contact added to your array :

```
  private int lastIndex = 0; // index of first available index of the array
  ...

  /**
   * Insert a new contact at the end
   */  
  public void add(String first, String last, String number){
     c=new Contact(first,last,number);
     if (lastIndex < MAX)
         contracts[lastIndex++]= c.toString();
  }
```

Some other issues with your code :

```
  /**
   * Return the first contact
   */  
  public String first() {
      return get(1); // should be get(0)
  }
```

Calling `toString()` for `contracts[i]` is redundant, since it's already a String. Perhaps you meant to store `Contact` instances instead of Strings in your array? That would make more sense.

Comment: The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int

Comment: @Niranjan Sorry, I didn't notice you already had a `last` parameter in that method. Renamed it to `lastIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an extra variable static int Last = 0; To track how many contact you have added and update the add function as .

   ```
   public void add(String first, String last, String number){
       if(Last>=MAX){ 
           System.out.println("Error in adding\n");
       }  
       else{
           c=new Contact(first,last,number);
           contacts[Last] = c.toString();
           Last++;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Change Tostring() for loop to last. So that you will be printing only added contact .In your case you are printing upto MAX that is wrong when less no of contacts are added.
3. You have to pass i=0,1,2,...,MAX-1 to get(i) function . Array is Zero(0) based indexed.

Comment: can you please explain me more about that toString() function ;   public String toString() {
   String s= "*";
   for(int i=0;i<current;i++){
    s=contracts[i].toString();
   }
   return s;
  }

Comment: i have a nullpointerexception in the result if i used this method !

Comment: e.g. You have added only 5 contacts to phonebook . And you are trying to access all MAX contacts.That is not required you can stop it by using Last index .

Comment: i want to display all the contracts that is added : but the methods just returns 1 contracts: in pb.toString() method call. why??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood all of your code right, but I think you are overwriting all other contacts in your phone book:

```
public void add(String first, String last, String number){
     c=new Contact(first,last,number); //(1)

    for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++){  //(2)
        contracts[i]= c.toString();
    }
```

}

At position (1) a new `Contact` object is created and assigned to `c`. In the next step (2), you loop through the array and assign the info contained in `c` (the latest contact added) to all already entries in the `contracts` array.

Independent from your problem, I suggest that you replace the array of a fixed size with i.e.  an ArrayList of type `Contact`. Adding entries to this list, iterating, sorting etc is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem you are having is that you always retrieve the last contact, regardless of which one you try to get. This is because when you add a new contact, you are actually replacing ALL the contacts, making them all the same. You are getting the correct contact from the phonebook, but they ALL have the same value.

To fix it, do the following:

```
public class PhoneBook
{
    int contactsAdded = 0; // Add an integer to store how many contacts you have added
    Contact[] contacts = new Contact[MAX]; //Change this to Contact array, not string
    //Contact c; //You can remove this line
    //Rest of your code
}

public void add(String first, String last, String number)
{
    //Only add if the number of contacts is less than the max
    if (contactsAdded < MAX)
    {
        //Construct the new contact when you use it.
        contacts[contactsAdded] = new Contact(first, last, number);
        contactsAdded++;
    }
}
```